# Mandatory constructor in subclass with a base class with constructor

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I have a base class named Base with a constructor. A subclass, named Sub, inherits the base class. However, because the subclass does not have a constructor, an error occurs:

```
public class Base {
    private int num;

    public Base(int n) {
        num = n;
    }
}

class Sub extends Base { // error: won't compile

}
```

Only when I code a constructor in the subclass will the error go away.
Why can't the constructor of the base class be called automatically whether there is a constructor in the subclass or not?

Comment: First you should always define constructors (excluding of course static classes). Second your subclass constructor must begin with `super()` to call the class constructor.

Comment: @Lutzi: almost -- the child's class's super call needs to include a String parameter to match the signature of the parent's constructor. Either that or give the parent an explicit no-arg constructor.